# Visual C++:error C2664: 'GetModuleFileNameW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWCH'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c2664

when I tried to compiling my project I got some errors that I can't solve.. anyway this is the one of the codes:

```
public:
void Init(HMODULE hModule, string Filename)
{
    char szLoc[ MAX_PATH ];
    GetModuleFileName(hModule, szLoc, sizeof( szLoc ) );
    char* dwLetterAddress = strrchr( szLoc, '\\' );
    *( dwLetterAddress + 1 ) = 0;
    strcat( szLoc, Filename.c_str() );
    __OutStream.open( szLoc, ios::app);
}
```

And the error is:

```
error C2664: 'GetModuleFileNameW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWCH'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style  cast or function-style cast
```

Thanks for help.. Regards, Messer

Comment: Your code doesn't call `GetModuleFileNameW`.  Have you left out something relevant?

Comment: Your code is compiling as unicode, but it's not. Either change the compilation options, change this function to use wide characters, or specifically call the ASCII version of the function -- `GetModuleFileNameA`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but your character set in Visual Studio might be set to "Use Unicode Character Set" under "Configuration Properties" > "General" of your project's properties.

Comment: @Carl Norum The windows header files will define GetModuleFileName to be either GetModuleFileNameA or GetModuleFileNameW depending on whether unicode is set of not

Comment: @Bart I think just the reverse, it's using a unicode build now and needs to be a multibyte character build for this to compile.

Comment: @JohnB That's what I'm suggesting. I'm not saying it should be set to that.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of the "functions" of the Windows API are actually macroes to either the ANSI (`A`) or Unicode (`W` for wide) version of the function. Depending on your project settings, these macroes will be either `DoSomeFunctionA` or `DoSomeFunctionW` when you want to call `DoSomeFunction`. The portable way would be then to use `TCHAR` because it is defined as `char` for ANSI and `wchar_t` for Unicode.

If you don't want to compile with Unicode, you can change your project settings to `Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set -> Use Multibyte Character Set`.

If you do want to compile with Unicode, then you should append an `A` (ex: `GetModuleFileNameA`) to the necessary function names.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @BlackBear For the last part? No. If you are compiling with Unicode then you have to explicitly call the ANSI function.